# How do I read and write the thorn character from a DAT file using quotechar in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Please see my code below. The code works as expected but the output DAT file is missing the þ (LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN) character.

```
import pandas as pd

inputdat = "C:/Downloads/Python/SAMPLEDATA.dat"
outputdat = "C:/Downloads/Python/Output.dat"

colnames = ["ID", "Company", "Employee", "Salary", 'Years']
df = pd.read_csv(inputdat, names = colnames, header = None, skiprows = 1, encoding='UTF-8', quotechar='\xfe', sep='\x14', engine='python')
filter = ['UID_001', 'UID_002']

df.loc[df.ID.isin(filter), ['Salary', 'Years']] = ""

df.to_csv(outputdat, quotechar='\xfe', sep='\x14', index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
```

How do I make sure the thorn symbol is included in the output dat?

SAMPLE INPUT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYVvO.jpg

CURRENT OUTPUT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gU8v.jpg

DESIRED OUTPUT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grtpI.jpg

Note: I apologize for posting the sample input and outputs in image form. The delimiter and quote characters were not showing up correctly otherwise.

Comment: change your encoding to latin-1

Comment: The input DAT is in UTF-8 so the output DAT also needs to be in UTF-8.

Comment: Oh I see, you need to set the level of quoting in your input and output. I can't reproduce your example so I can't post an answer but look at read_csv and to_csv docs on the `quoting` field

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by setting the level of quoting in input and output?

Comment: If you want to keep them in your output just remove `quotechar` from each of your df calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue you're facing is that quotes (thorn characters) are not being added because the default quoting discipline is `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`. Looks like you want `csv.QUOTE_ALL`:

```py
import csv

df.to_csv(outputdat, quotechar='\xfe', sep='\x14', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
          index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
```